# How to setup a connection to a remote mysql databse in express js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

**Problem:**

I have a database in a remote server 144.73.125.213 like this.

[image]

But when I try to access this from node application like this was led to an error.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : '144.73.125.213',
    port :"3306",
    user:"*******",
    password:"*******",
    database:"jobmelkc_jobme"
})
```

This is the error.

> Error in DB connection :{   "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",   "code":
>   "ETIMEDOUT",   "syscall": "connect",   "fatal": true }

I tried to telnet this server for this port but I was unable to do so. But when I ping to this server from terminal it was successful.

I tried solutions in some StackOverflow questions but I was unable to solve this issue. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: On your screenshot I see 'localhost', so i suppose you access it directly on the remote server, no ?  If yes, maybe should you check if there is no config that disallow the remote connection... Like ip filter or another kind of config...

Comment: @PimentoWeb yeah I got the screenshot directly from the server

Comment: @PimentoWeb How to check that kind of config?

Comment: Just google it : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/